# Concatenating esc_attr_e() to a variable issue in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, escaping, concatenation

i am trying to write wordPress search plugin. Everything is working fine but when i put all code inside my shortcode function then `esc_attr_e()` is not functioning inside php. i don't know how it works for me. here is my line:

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Search', 'woocommerce'); ?>" class="search"><span><?php esc_attr_e('Search','woocommerce');?></span></button>
```

and here is how i am trying to achieve this inside php:

```
<?php
$search = '<button type="submit" title="'.esc_attr_e('Search', 'woocommerce'). '" class="search"><span>';
$search .= ''.esc_attr_e('Search','woocommerce').'</span></button></form>';
?>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The function `esc_attr_e()` **echoes** (display) translated text that has been escaped, so that's why you get an issue as you are at the same time trying to concatenate it in a variable.

Instead use simply `esc_attr__()`function that can be concatenated without issues as it **returns** a translated text that has been escaped.

```
<?php
$search = '<button type="submit" title="'.esc_attr_e('Search', 'woocommerce'). '" class="search"><span>';
$search .= ''.esc_attr__('Search','woocommerce').'</span></button></form>';
?>
```